When I use the kmeans algorithm in jupyter notebook, the jupyter kernel keeps crashing
this is my code:
When I run to the last line of code, the Jupyter kernel keeps crashing, but no error is displayed in the terminal
At first I thought it was because of the conflict in the library version in my Python virtual environment, but when I ran this code in a recreated virtual environment to ensure there was no conflict, the jupyter kernel also crashed automatically, and it was not a problem with the large amount of data. I also tried the dbscan clustering algorithm, which worked fine, but the kmeans clustering kept having problems. My computer is running macOS, so I wonder if it's a memory-related problem?

I used gmm clustering again, and the result was the same kernel crash when running the same type of code,the code like this: df['Cluster_GMM'] = gmm.fit_predict(scaled_features)

Please read How do I ask a good question?, paying close attention to the headings 'Search, and Research' and 'Help others reproduce the problem'. In particular in the latter, it emphasizes in bold DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—. You had the code as text and could easily paste in as text in a fenced code block here. At such forums you are expected to help those that help you. Also you are supposed to be helping make a searchable and indexable database and the bulk of the info in an image is not appropriate.
